# dim formula as integer

Tags: excel, vba

A stupid question is how can I dim a formula as integer ?
Say count the value in Column A with formula "counta(a2:a10)"
if Column A contains value in 3 cells , then 3 will be the integer, how can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

The formulas are available as actual functions in VBA through `Application.Worksheetfunction`.

You can use them like

```
    Dim n As Long
    n = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Me.Range("A1:A10"))
    Debug.Print n
```

Make sure that you do not just use `...(Range` but always address the proper worksheet object as with `Me` or `Worksheets("Name").Range(...` for example.

Besides, you can also use [Evaluate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/ff193019.aspx).

```
n = [CountA(Table1!A1:A10)]
```

which is equal to

```
n = Application.Evaluate("CountA(Table1!A1:A10)")
```

Answer (score 1):

you use INT, however  COUNTA can only return an integer so its not necessary.

```
=INT(COUNTA(A2:A10))
```

In VBA you would do like so

```
Dim intCount as Integer
intCount = Application.CountA(Range("A2:A10"))
```

You can also do ( but not necessary as above)

```
Dim intCount as Integer
intCount = CInt(Application.CountA(Range("A2:A10")))
```

**Note: As of Excel 2007 , type Long should be used instead of Integer for column ranges**